# Running WSO2 IS on Ubuntu - CARBON cannot execute Java

Tags: bash, permissions, java, jdk

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit. I'm logged in to Ubuntu as `user1`. I installed Oracle JDK version jdk1.8.0_144 to `/usr/local/java` and set symlinks as

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/java" 1
$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/javac" 1
$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/javaws" 1
$ sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/java
$ sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/javac
$ sudo update-alternatives --set javaws /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/javaws
```

Then I added the following in `~/.bashrc` file.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

I installed wso2 IS server in `/opt` directly by creating a subdirectory under `/opt` such that `/opt/wso2/is`.

When I try to run the server using `sh wso2server.sh` I get the `Permission Denied` error. However, when I try `sudo sh wso2server.sh` I get the error

```
JAVA_HOME is not correctly defined.
CARBON cannot execute java.
```

However, when I run `echo JAVA_HOME` it shows the correct location of java.

The permissions of the relevant directories are:

```
$ ls -ld /opt/wso2/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep 8 20:02 /opt/wso2

$ ls -l /opt/wso2/is
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4096 Sep 8 23:11 wso2is-5.3.0
```

My questions are:

1. How to resolve the error `CARBON cannot execute java`?
2. What is the proper way to deploy/run this java application without having to use `sudo`?

Clarifications:

1. Application I'm trying to run: Identity Server from WSO2.
2. How did I install IS: I downloaded the installation file which is a `zip` file and extracted that to `/opt` using `sudo unzip ~/Downloads -d /opt/wso2/is`.
3. Why did I choose `/opt`: I'm new to Linux. My understanding was if I'm installing a software manually I should use `/usr/local` (for software like java runtime) or `/opt` for binaries. Not sure if this is correct.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output of `ls -ld  /opt/wso2/` and `ls -l /opt/wso2/is`. You created the directory as root so you probably just need to give your user execute rights to it to be able to run without sudo. Also, do you mean `~/.bashrc` or did you actually use `/.bashrc`? Finally, how do you log into this machine? Do you have physical access or are you connecting via ssh or something similar?

Comment: @terdon updated to include the information. I login directly to the VM using username and password. I'm running it in dev environment in a virtual box.

Comment: OK, we also need the output of `ls -l /opt/wso2/is/wso2server.sh`. And you haven't given us the exact command you use top run it. Do you first `cd /opt/wso2/is/` and then `sh wso2server.sh`? And why are you using `sh`? Does it work if you just run `/opt/wso2/is/wso2server.sh`? Finally, what is the first line of `/opt/wso2/is/wso2server.sh`? Is it `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh` or something else?

Comment: I first `cd` to `/opt/wso2/is/wso2is-5.3.0/bin` and run `sh wso2server.sh`. The `sh` in front was supposed to be run according to docs from devs. When I try without it, I get `command not found` error. When I run `ls -l /opt/wso2/is/wso2is-5.3.0/bin/wso2server.sh` I get `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10493 Dec 21 2016 /opt/wso2/is/wso2is-5.3.0/bin/wso2server.sh`. @terdon